# Loop images, java gui?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel, imageicon

I'm trying to create a java program that generates 10 playing cards. The playing cards are in gif format. I have tried to put these in an array, but do not know how I get on. The playing cards should ideally be displayed without the strict placement. The cards are left anyway. Would need tips to get ahead. As it stands now, I get no error message. But the box that comes up, is empty. What should I do?

Thanks in advance

**cards.java**

```
public abstract class cards extends JPanel {

Random gen = new Random();
int noOfCards = 10;
int line;
int col;
boolean faceUp;
String back = "img/b2fv.gif";
JLabel[] stackLabel = new JLabel[noOfCards];
ImageIcon[] stack = new ImageIcon[noOfCards];

ImageIcon [][]  cards = {
        {new ImageIcon("img/c1.gif"), new ImageIcon("img/d1.gif"), new ImageIcon("img/h1.gif") , new ImageIcon("img/s1.gif")},
        {new ImageIcon("img/c2.gif"), new ImageIcon("img/d2.gif"), new ImageIcon("img/h2.gif") , new ImageIcon("img/s2.gif")},
        {new ImageIcon("img/c3.gif"), new ImageIcon("img/d3.gif"), new ImageIcon("img/h3.gif") , new ImageIcon("img/s3.gif")},
        {new ImageIcon("img/c4.gif"), new ImageIcon("img/d4.gif"), new ImageIcon("img/h4.gif") , new ImageIcon("img/s4.gif")},
        {new ImageIcon("img/c5.gif"), new ImageIcon("img/d5.gif"), new ImageIcon("img/h5.gif") , new ImageIcon("img/s5.gif")},
        {new ImageIcon("img/c6.gif"), new ImageIcon("img/d6.gif"), new ImageIcon("img/h6.gif") , new ImageIcon("img/s6.gif")},
        {new ImageIcon("img/c7.gif"), new ImageIcon("img/d7.gif"), new ImageIcon("img/h7.gif") , new ImageIcon("img/s7.gif")},
        {new ImageIcon("img/c8.gif"), new ImageIcon("img/d8.gif"), new ImageIcon("img/h8.gif") , new ImageIcon("img/s8.gif")},
        {new ImageIcon("img/c9.gif"), new ImageIcon("img/d9.gif"), new ImageIcon("img/h9.gif") , new ImageIcon("img/s9.gif")},
        {new ImageIcon("img/c10.gif"), new ImageIcon("img/d10.gif"), new ImageIcon("img/h10.gif") , new ImageIcon("img/s10.gif")},
        {new ImageIcon("img/cj.gif"), new ImageIcon("img/dj.gif"), new ImageIcon("img/hj.gif") , new ImageIcon("img/sj.gif")},
        {new ImageIcon("img/cq.gif"), new ImageIcon("img/dq.gif"), new ImageIcon("img/hq.gif") , new ImageIcon("img/sq.gif")},
        {new ImageIcon("img/ck.gif"), new ImageIcon("img/dk.gif"), new ImageIcon("img/hk.gif") , new ImageIcon("img/sk.gif")},
        {new ImageIcon("img/jr.gif"), new ImageIcon("img/jb.gif")}
};

public JLabel[] genCards(){
    try{
        for(int i = 0; i < noOfCards; i++){
            line = gen.nextInt(14);
            col = gen.nextInt(4);
            faceUp = gen.nextBoolean();

            stack[i] = cards[line][col];
            stackLabel[i] = new JLabel();
            ImageIcon img;
            stackLabel[i].setIcon(img = stack[i]);
            this.add(stackLabel[i]);
        }
    }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
        System.out.println(e);
        System.out.println("Problem med array");
    }
    return stackLabel;
}
}
```

**table.java**

```
public class table extends cards {

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);

    for(int i = 0; i < this.stackLabel.length; i++){
        //System.out.println(stack[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ImageIcon is a Swing component, so just add those ImageIcons to a container like a JPanel (perhaps that Cards extends JPanel you have). The container itself draws the Swing components it contains, so you don't have to manually draw them.

Answer (score 1):

At least you have to call to genCards() somewhere. Probably in constructor or a init method:

```
public Cards(){
    genCards();
}
```